# Do I have to install all three ESSENTIAL BUSINESS SERVERS?

Tags: amazon-ebs, windows-server-essentials

We are currently thinking about deploying [Essential Business Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/ebs/en/us/default.aspx) at our head-office. My question is that do I have to install all three of the servers provided by EBS ie MANAGEMENT, MESSAGING, SECURITY?

Can I leave out the MESSAGING server as I really can't think of a use for it at this stage ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to install all the servers. Only those you require.

Comment: Are you really sure about this? I investigated this earlier when considering buying EBS and I found out that I had to install the security suite in order to get exchange working properly (namely web access).